# Sending text plain header in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have an action that lets the customer preview system email messages and i want to send a `text/plain` header for the plaintext versions of the emails.

I tried to follow the [Symfony docs : Requests and Responses in Symfony](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_fundamentals.html#requests-and-responses-in-symfony) section. However my controller is sending a `text/html` content-type no matter what i do.

This is my action:

```
function showAction($action = null, $format = null){

   $locale = $this->get('session')->getLocale();
   $format = $this->getRequest()->get("format");
   $format = isset($format) ? $format : 'html';


   if ($format === 'text'){
       $response = new Response();
       $response->headers->set('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
       $response->sendHeaders();

   }

   $view = sprintf('MyBundle:Email:%s.%s.%s.twig', 
         $action,$locale,$format);

   return $this->render($view, array());
}
```

So how do I send a text plain header and where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add $response to render call

```
return $this->render($view, array(), $response);
```